# If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $f\circ g$ measurable. What's wrong with my proof?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ Lebesgue measurable. Set $$H_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2-1}\frac{k}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{\frac{k}{n}\leq f(x)<\frac{k+1}{n}\}}(x).$$

Then $H_n(x)\to f(x)$ when $n\to \infty $. Since $g$ is measurable, then so is $H_n(g(x))$ because $\boldsymbol 1_{\frac{k}{n}\leq f(g(x))\leq\frac{k+1}{n} }$ and $$H_n(g(x))=\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2-1}\frac{k}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{\frac{k}{n}\leq f(g(x))<\frac{k+1}{n}}(x).$$

Since $H_n(g(\cdot ))$ is measurable for all $n$ and converges pointwise to $f(g(\cdot ))$, we conclude that $f(g(\cdot ))$ is measurable.

What is wrong ? (because I know that $f\circ g$ may be not measurable).

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is a Borel function, your argument is correct, but if $f$ is Leabesgue measurable but not Borel, then $\boldsymbol 1_{\{\frac{k}{n}\leq f(x)<\frac{k+1}{n}\}}=\boldsymbol 1_{f^{-1}[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})}$ may be not Borel, and thus $\boldsymbol 1_{\{\frac{k}{n}\leq f(g(x))<\frac{k+1}{n}\}}=\boldsymbol 1_{g^{-1}(f^{-1}[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}))}$ is a priori not measurable.

Comment: Right. I think "...is not a priori measurable" would be more accurate than "...is a priori not measurable"...